# If $\omega$ is a primitive cube root of unity, simplify ${\omega}^{{2009}^{{2009}^{{2009}^{\cdots 2009}}}}$

Tags: complex-analysis, elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, solution-verification

> Let $\omega$ be a primitive cube root of unity.  Let $x = {\omega}^{{2009}^{{2009}^{{2009}^{\cdots 2009}}}}$ (up to $2009$ times). Simplify the value of $x$.

**My attempt:** Let $m =  {{2009}^{{2009}^{{2009}^{\cdots 2009}}}}$ (up to $2007$ times). Then since $2009$ is odd so $2009^m$ is also odd. Let $k = 2009^m$. Now since $k$ is an odd integer so $2^k \equiv 2\ (\text {mod}\ 3)$. Also $2009 \equiv 2\ (\text {mod}\ 3)$. Therefore, $2009^k \equiv 2\ (\text {mod}\ 3)$. Let $n = 2009^k$. Then $n = 3k' + 2$ for some $k' \in \Bbb N$. Therefore $$x = {\omega}^n = {\omega}^2$$

Am I right? Please verify it.

Thanks in advance for reading.

Comment: You did not say what $\omega$ is

Comment: @Didlier $\omega$ is a primitive cube root of unity.

Comment: Yep, you're right

Comment: As which primitive root $\omega$ is is not specified and the answer seems to be unambiguous, then it must be $1$.

Comment: @Yves Daoust what must be $1$? If $\omega$ is a primitive cube root of unity then how can $\omega^2 = 1$? Usually $\frac {-1 + \sqrt 3 i} {2}$ is considered as $\omega.$ But then $\omega^2 = \frac {-1 - \sqrt 3 i} {2} \neq 1.$

Comment: You may also take $\omega = \frac {-1 - \sqrt 3 i} {2}$ in which case $\omega^2 = \frac {-1 + \sqrt 3 i} {2} \neq 1.$ Your answer seems quite ambiguous to me.

Comment: The answer is one of $\omega$, $\omega^2$ or $1$. But as $\omega$ is not specified, I infer $1$. [Jus kidding ;-) ]

Comment: @Yves Daoust I have seen the word "kidding" in many places. Can we use "kid" as a verb?

Comment: @mathmaniac.https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/kid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is $\omega^2$ and your method is right and check my method
$2009^{odd} $can be written as ${(2010-1)}^{odd}$.
That is $2010 \times m - 1$($m$ is some integer), as $2010$ is divisible by $3$ it is $\frac1{\omega} = \omega^2$

Comment: Very nice answer.

Comment: Thank u bro....

Answer (score 1):

$2009$ can be expressed as $6m-1$ where $m$ is any integer

Now observe that $(6m-1)^{6m-1}\equiv-1\pmod6,$ so again of the form $6m'-1$

If $w$ is a root of unity,

$$w^{6n-1}=(w^3)^{2n-1}w^2=?$$

Comment: math maniac's answer is pretty neat than that of yours. I don't know why did you post it? Is the increment of reputation your only goal? (so called Midnapurians).

Comment: @Anacardium, Wish you could understand the nicety of the generalization !  Midnapurians! where are you from?

Comment: I am from Shyambazar,Kolkata.